# How to import css file into 1 page only on ionic2?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

For example i want to import this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">
```

to example_page. I try import this from the index.html but i think if i use this way this css will be loaded on all page every time i run my app. Is there a better way for importing my css only for 1 page?

Comment: Why don't you copy the content of that file in the `page.scss` file instead?

Comment: @sebaferreras ya copy the whole css is something i ever tried, but i want to learn more if there is a way to importing the css only for some page

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your mycss.css into your example_page component's css file. This way it will only work for that component only.